# Is there a difference using the en dash with spaces and em dash without spaces?

Tags: grammar, em-dashes

I’ve noticed that both en dashes with spaces and em dashes with no spaces are used in some reports I'm reading. My understanding is that **(B)** below would be correct usage. (In MS Word the em dahses shown in example **(B)** below are much longer.)

Is there any difference or are one of these a mistake?

**(A)**
Although this program was developed by building on its experiences in studying ARR in other contexts – particularly in the COMP process – the exact outline has not yet been implemented.

**(B)**
The company believes that the framework is most effective—in terms of adopting review criteria and channeling research into RRA safety measures—if it focusses on actions that pursue specific levels of autonomy.

Comment: You can use any style of dash or spacing you like as long as you're consistent. Mixing styles is a mistake (although easily done, especially if you don't have a corporate style guide or any proper editors). If you search here for em dash, you'll get a bunch of similar questions about what formats are valid for dashes. [For example this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9070/is-it-wrong-to-space-en-dashes-and-em-dashes).

Comment: And this one: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/154996/spaces-and-em-dash