# Spacing around an em dash

Tags: punctuation, spacing

Should an em dash have spaces around it?

I always thought it shouldn't have spaces, but I [recently read](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Dash#Spacing_and_substitution) that in some cultures it is common to include spaces:

> [...] the "space, en dash, space" sequence is the predominant style in German and French typography.

I have also heard of the use of a [hair space](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Hair_space) on either side of the dash in some contexts:

> [...] an em dash should always be set closed, meaning it should not be surrounded by spaces.  But the practice in some parts of the Enlgish-speaking world [...] sets it open, separating it from its surrounding words by using spaces or hair spaces (`U+200A`) when it is being used parenthetically.

In fact, we can see this hair space on either side being desired outcome [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/412764/).

Conversely, [some say](https://www.reddit.com/r/grammar/comments/9uosld/) it's merely a matter of style/personal preference.

Is there a rule or tradition I should follow?  If, in the context described above, set open is preferable, should I use a normal space (`U+0020`) or a hair space (`U+200A`)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it wrong to space en dashes and em dashes?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9070/is-it-wrong-to-space-en-dashes-and-em-dashes) (To summarise, no spaces were formerly usual but now spaces are increasingly common and you can do what you like.) Note that questions about German or French typography are off-topic here and should be asked on the SEs for the relevant languages.

Comment: Thanks @StuartF, I didn't see that question when researching, but that does answer my question.  There's even a comment there talking about hair spaces.  P.S., I'm not particularly interested in German or French, just mentioned that to add context to my question.

Comment: This is a typographical style question. I have worked at publications that required spaces and others that did not use spaces. Nowadays, everybody uses hyphens instead of dashes, and without spaces, it creates a compound word, so having spaces seems best.